# Can my Azure Mobile Service run locally?

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I am new to Azure. I am following this tutorial in setting up my .Net server for azure and ios client.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-ios-get-started/

I am testing my ios client on simulator. Can I run my .NET server on my location machine with put publish it to azure? If yes, how can I figure my client to talks to this location machine?

And in the tutorial, it creates a Database Table. If I run it locally, do I need to setup my location DB server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not on a mac (which you need for iOS development). With the .NET backend you can run the service locally on a Windows machine, but it will be running off of localhost.

For iOS development, you have two choices. If you use the JavaScript / node.js backend, where all of your development can be done in the Mac (you can configure the service via Git locally or directly in the portal). If you use the .NET backend (the link you mentioned), then you need the Mac for the client-side development, and a PC (or Windows running in the Mac on an emulator such as parallels) to develop the server (you need Visual Studio for that).

And regarding your question about the table, when you run it locally, it will use Entity Framework Code First (by default), so you don't need to create the table in your (local) database - it will create it automatically for you.

Comment: I have a Windows machine for my .NET backend. And an Mac laptop for the iOS development. What do I need to change in the ios project code I download from Azure so that my ios client can talk to my local host running .NET backend?

Comment: Although I haven't tried it, you should be able to host the service in your *local IIS* (not IIS Express), and that will make it visible from other machines - you'll need to change it on the properties of the service project. At that point, if your Mac (or more importantly, the iOS emulator) can see the PC in the network, I think it should be able to access the service that way.